# Move the position of shapefile objects automatically

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openshift

I have a shapefile with a big number of polygon objects. The problem is that these objects have a systematic shift.

Is there any possibility to place them all at the right position automatically using Python- or GDAL- scripts?

I'm using QGIS 2.10 on a Ubuntu 15.04 System.

Comment: What CRS do your shapefiles have? How large is the shift (in meters or degrees)? Why have you tagged the question with openshift?